# Connection Error with Metro IRC

Tags: irc

Upon Downloading Metro IRC I have been having problems with adding a network. http://prntscr.com/2c027a   I tried everything possible but it keep's saying that it can't connect. I am trying to connect to #freenode on Metro IRC but it doesn't't work please help.

Comment: what server address are you using ?